Using api to select all files on android
I am developing an android app using API 26+ which will allow users to select various files be it documents, videos, images or apps and send them to the server.
The server module is ready but the client side is still in progress. I need a way to select files on android devices. I tried using content resolver as shown below:
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("*/*");

However, this approach does not allow selecting apps. So I decided to create a button which when clicked will open a window with widgets containing all the installed apps on the device.
I am planning to create a dictionary where the key is the path to the application obtained using the string String publicSourceDir = packageInfo.publicSourceDir, and the value is the name of this application (packageInfo.packageName) or its logo.
When the user clicks on the widget with the desired application, it is copied to the directory of my application. Then bytes are read from it and sent to the server. However, I am afraid that APK files will not be able to be transmitted over the Internet, and I cannot find a solution to this problem.
Please tell me how to overcome this difficulty?
Intent intent = new Intent();
final PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
// Get the list of installed applications
@SuppressLint("QueryPermissionsNeeded")
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo: packages) {
 String publicSourceDir = packageInfo.publicSourceDir;
 System.out.println(packageInfo.packageName);
}


"APK files will not be able to be transmitted over the Internet" -- what you are describing may be illegal in your jurisdiction (please talk to an attorney!). However, it is unclear why you think it may not be possible from a technical standpoint.

@CommonsWare  I apologize I wrote it wrong I meant when I select the desired apk file android will not let me copy bytes from it
